# 3D surface plotting : plot the intersection of 2 surfaces

Tags: python, plot, 3d

Here is my project :
I need to plot a surface which is the arera of the paraboloid (in blue) contained into the red cylinder.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0OqM.png)

here is the code to generate the data of the 2 surfaces :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

# Cylinder parameters
cyl_radius = 6.35
cyl_height = 10000
cyl_samples = 100
cyl_theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, cyl_samples)
cyl_x = cyl_radius * np.cos(cyl_theta) + 50.8
cyl_y = cyl_radius * np.sin(cyl_theta) + 1
cyl_z = np.linspace(0, cyl_height, cyl_samples)
cyl_z = np.linspace(0, cyl_height, cyl_samples)
cyl_z = cyl_z.reshape((len(cyl_z), 1))

# Paraboloid parameters
para_a = 16.29/25.5
para_b = 100
para_res = 1000
para_axis_pt = np.array([0, 1, 0])

# Generate paraboloid coordinates
para_theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, para_res)
para_r = np.linspace(0, para_b, para_res)
para_r, para_theta = np.meshgrid(para_r, para_theta)
para_x = para_r * np.cos(para_theta) #+ para_axis_pt[0]
para_y = para_r * np.sin(para_theta)# + para_axis_pt[1]
para_z = para_a * para_r**2 #+ para_axis_pt[2]

# Plot the cylinder and paraboloid
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(para_y, para_x, para_z, color='blue')
ax.plot_surface(cyl_x, cyl_y, cyl_z, color='red')
# ax.plot_surface(cyl_x, cyl_y, -cyl_z, color='red')

# Add labels and set equal aspect ratio
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
ax.set_aspect('auto')

plt.show()
```

The cylinder has a centre of (50.8,0) and a diameter of 12.5.

Then I tried to add a mask using `numpy.ma`

like this :

```
Zm=ma.masked_where((para_y + np.full_like(para_y, 50.8))**2 + para_x**2 >= cyl_radius**2,para_z)
```

then plotted the new surface like this :

```
ax.plot_surface(para_x, para_y, ma.getmask(Zm), color='green')
```

But here is my result :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEg0w.png)

I tried to apply the mask on para_x and para_y also :

```
Xm=ma.masked_where((para_y + np.full_like(para_y, 50.8))**2 + para_x**2 >= cyl_radius**2,para_x)

Ym=ma.masked_where((para_y + np.full_like(para_y, 50.8))**2 + para_x**2 >= cyl_radius**2,para_y)
```

But I have the same issues...

I checked that the vectors Xm, Ym and Zm were not completely masked.